# ConcurrentHashmap Segments and Rehashing

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

Trying to understand concurrent hashmap had few questions?

1. Does every segment share the same hashmap or every segment has its own hashmap?
2. What happens when rehashing of the segment hashmap is needed and there is a thread writing to another segment?

Comment: Why not to check the source code for that class? It has very descriptive comments

Comment: 1) this question makes no sense. A `ConcurrentHashMap` has one or more segments, not the other way round. 2) Rehashing of one segment has no impact on other segments. 3) This is outdated stuff anyway, as since Java 8, there are no segments anymore.